# How to add a library that is not for laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, api, laravel-4, contextio

I have this Library from Context.io
https://github.com/contextio/contextio-php-example

The Context.io 2.0 has laravel, 
The Context.io Lite does not.

Im Using The Lite version because its Free.

I would like the Context.io Lite Library installed in my Laravel 4.2.

How to add Context.io Lite Library in my Laravel 4.2 application?

Additional Information:

- Im developing an API
- Using PHP laravel 4.2
- I want to integrate Context.io Lite
- Context.io Lite Library does not have many files. Just 4 files.php

Comment: ive been looking for this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a developer on the Context.IO team, though only passingly familiar with Laravel. Laravel uses [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) so it should be simple to add the [Lite library](https://github.com/contextio/PHP-Lite-ContextIO). Just add this to your `composer.json` file, which should be in the root of your Laravel project:

`"require": { "contextio/php-contextio-lite": "dev-master" }`

Then run `composer install` from the command line to install the library.

The [example](https://github.com/contextio/contextio-php-example) project can give you some basics to help you get started. Also, don't hesitate to contact the dev team at `support@context.io` for additional support if you need it.

Comment: ill try this hehe thank you for answering, your the person from Context.io thats been replying me in gmail hahaha :P

Comment: is there a way to add email programmatically? that i don't have to redirect to some URL. I already have the credentials no need for me to go and type again. Is that possible?